# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'left')

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress-theming

I'm having trouble with a WordPress theme, it seems something easy to solve, but I have no idea where to start haha.

I'm getting the following error in my console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'left')     at X (main.min.js?ver=6.3.2:1:50679)     at main.min.js?ver=6.3.2:1:58007     at dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.0:2:39997)     at v.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.0:2:37968)`

Here is the line/code in question:

```js
     function X() {
        var t = e("#content").outerWidth()
          , a = (e("#content").offset().left,
        t / 2 - e("#content .page-container").width() / 2)
          , i = function(e, t, i, s) {
            var o = e.find("> .wpb_column > .vc_column-inner");
            t && (o = e.find("> .split-box-container")),
            i && (o = e.find("> .parallax-content")),
            o = s ? o.last() : o.eq(0),
            Clb.isMobile || o.css("padding-" + (s ? "right" : "left"), a + "px")
        }
          , s = function(e, a, i) {
            var s = e.find(a ? "> .split-box-container" : "> .wpb_column > .vc_column-inner > .wpb_wrapper");
            (s = i ? s.last() : s.eq(0)).css({
                position: "",
                left: "",
                width: ""
            }),
            s.length && (i ? s.css("width", t - s.offset().left + "px") : s.css({
                position: "relative",
                left: -s.offset().left + "px",
                width: s.offset().left + s.outerWidth() + "px"
            }),
            Clb.isMobile && s.css({
                width: "",
                left: ""
            }))
        };
        e(".clb-column-padding-left").each(function() {
            i(e(this), e(this).hasClass("split-box"), e(this).hasClass("parallax"), !1)
        }),
        e(".clb-column-padding-right").each(function() {
            i(e(this), e(this).hasClass("split-box"), e(this).hasClass("parallax"), !0)
        }),
        e(".clb-stretch-column-left").each(function() {
            s(e(this), e(this).hasClass("split-box"), !1)
        }),
        e(".clb-stretch-column-right").each(function() {
            s(e(this), e(this).hasClass("split-box"), !0)
        })
    }
```

Any idea how I could fix it? This is breaking my entire checkout :/

I've tried updating my theme and turning off all my plugins, but nothing helped, the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `e("#content").offset()` is returning null.

One solution is solving the function by checking if `e("#content").offset()` exists, and only then try to use the .left.

`e("#content")?.offset()` should solve it but it can create further errors as you need to check if the variable "a" from `a = (e("#content").offset()?.left` is also not null.

As it's a WordPress error, the best solution is to make "#content" visible by adding `id="content"` to a div or discover why #content is not in the page.